# Difference between concatenation of anys in map versus function

Tags: scala

I've got an array of elements of Type Any. I'm using some values to concatenate them to a String in one line inside a map declaration:

```
val mapRequest = Map(
    "the_geom" -> "CDB_LatLng(" + row(2).toString() + ", " + row(3).toString() + ")"
)
```

This gives me that error which I don't understand:

```
[error] /path/to/file/Signal.scala:92: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : String
[error]  required: (?, ?)
```

When I put that concatenation inside a function and use it like this:

```
val mapRequest = Map(
    "the_geom" -> Utils.getGeom(row(2), row(3))
)
```

Where the function getGeom is defined like this:

```
def getGeom(lat:Any, lon:Any) : String = {
    return "CDB_LatLng(" + lat.toString() + ", " + lon.toString() + ")"
}
```

Everything works.

Can you explain what is different to have that expression of concatenation inside a Map declaration vs a function declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
Map(
  "the_geom" -> ("CDB_LatLng(" + row(2).toString() + ", " + row(3).toString() + ")")
)
```

You are trying to instanciate a Map with the tuple `"the_geom" -> "CDB_LatLng("` concatenated with some string, because of the Synthetic Function `+`, which will assume that both sides are being represented as String, if not otherwise specified. The function scope of `getGeom` provides this scope for you, saving you the parantheses. If you wrap the String concatenation in parentheses, the value within will be evaluated before the tuple operation. In this case, just read it from left to right, and it makes sense.